# One div inside another, both clickable. When pressing the inner one, the outer is also triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

what I would like to achieve is something like that: I have some div (a blog post to be precise, like Reddit) and I want this div to be whole clickable. It has a lot of data, like the author, time posted, content, img, etc. But on the bottom is a save button which allows users to save it for later. But when I click the save button it also triggers the post's onlick what causes that user is redirected to the detail page of the post. I do not want that. I only want to trigger the save button. Image of the situation:

[image: Image of situation.]

What I do have is that:

```html
<div onclick="location.href='/post/{{ post.id }}/';" style="cursor: pointer; ">
    <article class="media post">
        <div class="media-body">

            <!-- Whole body, user, date, content, img etc. -->

            <div>
                <a id="save-post-{{post.id}}" href="javascript:void(0);"
                    onclick="save_post('{{post.pk}}', '{{user.pk}}', this.id, '{{ csrf_token }}');">
                    Save
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </article>
</div>
```

`save-post` is the AJAX function, that sends data to the Django server.

How do I do that, the save button is only triggered?

Comment: [event.stopPropagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation)

Comment: You can change the html structure little bit.

Comment: remove the onclick="location.href='/post/{{ post.id }}/';" from outer div ,you can pass it in save_post function as a arument and fire inside the save_post function

Comment: `save_post(e, yourValue) { process ajax call; e.stopImmediatePropagation(); }`

Comment: @PatrickEvans and Rijo anwsers solved my problem, thank you.

Comment: Give higher z-index to save button: `<a style="z-index:25; position: absolute">`

Answer (score 0):

Just rearrange your htm a bit like this

```
<div>
<article class="media post">
    <div class="media-body"  onclick="location.href='/post/{{ post.id }}/';" style="cursor: pointer; ">

        <!-- Whole body, user, date, content, img etc. -->


    </div>
    <div>
            <a id="save-post-{{post.id}}" href="javascript:void(0);"
                onclick="save_post('{{post.pk}}', '{{user.pk}}', this.id, '{{ csrf_token }}');">
                Save
            </a>
        </div>
</article>

 </div>
```